# Joint density with restrain

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I can't solve this problem...tried several areas for limits of integration but solution just doesn't match with solution from end of textbook (Stirzaker:Probability and random variables).

Exercise 6.6.2
Let X and Y have joint density

$$f(x,y)=e^{-y}$$ 
$$0<x<y<\infty$$

Find joint density for Z=X+Y.

I just can't figure it up and became really frustrated, especially being self-learner. I haven't write any of my trials because I only ask for someone to please help me with bounds of integration(I know formula for joint density etc.)

Many thanks!

Comment: What density do you mean? $f(x,y)=e^y$?

Comment: That density doesn't integrate to 1 so something is wrong

Comment: @user2879934: it does now

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Sorry, forgot :/ Find joint density for Z=X+Y

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean
$$f(x,y)=e^{-y}$$ for the density and the problem is to verify that this is a distribution, the integral is 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^ye^{-y}dxdy$$
which after some calculus...

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_0^\infty[e^{-y}x|_0^ydy$$
$$=\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy$$
which we can be tricky and write as 
$$=\frac{1}{e}\int_0^\infty ye^{-y+1}dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{e}\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dy} e^{-y+1}dy$$
and using integral of derivative is derivative of integral
$$=\frac{1}{e}e^{-y+1}|_0^\infty$$
$$=\frac{e}{e}$$
EDIT:
To find the joint density $Z=X+Y$ then you can either apply the convolution formula or use standard transformation of variables, let's do the second.
Define $$U=X,V=X+Y$$
so $$g_1(X,Y)=X,g_2(Y)=X+Y$$
so we need to find the inverse transformation which is given by 
$$g_1^{-1}(U,V)=U,g_2^{-1}(U,V) = V-U$$

Okay so we know that the transformation of random variables is given by 
$$f_{U,V}(U,V)=f_{X,Y}(g_1^{-1}(U,V),g_2^{-1}(U,V)|J|$$
where $J$ is the jacobian is the derivative of 
$$g_1^{-1}(U,V),g_2^{-1}(U,V)$$ with respect to $U,V$
This gives $1$ after some computation (ask in comments if you want to see it).

So plugging in for our density we get
$$f_{U,V}(U,V)=f_{X,Y}(U,V-U)$$
$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=e^{u-v}$$
So now we want to integrate out $U$ this is where the support comes in
if $$0<x<y<\infty$$ then we can write this as 
$$\{(x,y) | x<y\}$$
$$\{(u,v) | 2u < v\}$$

so we get the final answer as 
$$\int_0^{\frac{v}{2}}e^{u-v}du$$
Which if you plug into wolfram alpha (or do some hard calculus) as 
`integral from 0 to v/2 of e^(u-v) du` gives you the desired answer (where I used $v=X+Y$ instead of $Z=X+Y$)

Comment: Thanks, but answer in solutions is $$f_{Z}(z)=e^{-z/2} - e^{-z}$$

Comment: hold on i'm getting there :)

Comment: okay I updated my answer

Comment: Is there any possibility to help me with hint or something to solve this via convolution? This example is introduced in chapter with convolution, few chapters before change of variables. Thanks for above answer!

Comment: Sure, you can get to the joint density of U,V as $e^{u-v}$ by applying the convolution formula